# Как сделать общий список / словарь / тюпл на два экземпляра класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы результат(ы) метода `play()` добавлялись в общий список `__log` для разных экземпляров класса? т.е. грубо говоря есть два игрока(экземпляра класса) и необходимо чтобы каждый их ход записывался в общий лог. Просто на сколько я понимаю в таком виде как сейчас `__log` будет свой для каждого экземпляра класса...
Спасибо!

```
from random import randint


class SnakesLadders:
    __log = []
    snakechecks = {16: 6, 46: 25, 49: 11, 62: 19, 64: 60, 74: 53, 89: 68, 92: 88, 95: 75, 99: 80}
    ladderchecks = {2: 38, 7: 14, 8: 31, 15: 26, 21: 42, 28: 84, 36: 44, 51: 67, 71: 91, 78: 98, 87: 94}

    def __init__(self, coord):
        self.__coord = coord

    @staticmethod
    def snake(coord):  
        snakecoords = SnakesLadders.snakechecks.get(coord)
        return snakecoords

    @staticmethod
    def ladder(coord):  
        laddercoords = SnakesLadders.snakechecks.get(coord)
        return laddercoords

    def statistics(self):  
        return self.__log

    def play(self):
        self.__coord += randint(2, 12)
        if self.__coord in SnakesLadders.snakechecks:
            self.__coord = type(self).snake(self.__coord)    
            return self.__coord
        if self.__coord in SnakesLadders.ladderchecks:
            self.__coord = type(self).ladder(self.__coord)     
            return self.__coord
        else:
            return self.__coord


player1 = SnakesLadders(0)
player2 = SnakesLadders(0)
print(player1.play())
print(player2.play())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная __log принадлежит всему классу, а не отдельному экземпляру. Для ее изменения для всех экземпляров, необходимо обращаться к ней через класс `SnakesLadders.__log`. Если задать ее значение через экземпляр, то `__log` этого экземпляра более не будет возвращать значение `__log` класса.

### Пример

```
class SomeInstance:
    variable = "Hello, "

some_a = SomeInstance()
some_b = SomeInstance()

'''
При изменении variable конкретного экземпляра
some_a, some_a.variable становится независимой
от SomeInstance.variable.
'''
some_a.variable = "Bye, "
# Продемонстрируем это: изменим SomeInstance.variable.
SomeInstance.variable += "Charlotte!"

print(some_a.variable)# Bye, 
print(hex(id(some_a.variable)))# Запоминаем адрес переменной.
print()
'''
some_b.variable явно не изменялась,
но она зависит от SomeInstance.variable.
То есть some_b.variable ссылается на
SomeInstance.variable.
'''
print(some_b.variable)# Hello, Charlotte!
print(SomeInstance.variable)# Hello, Charlotte!
print(hex(id(some_b.variable)))
print(hex(id(SomeInstance.variable)))
'''
Адрес some_a.variable отличен
от равных some_b.variable и
SomeInstance.variable.
'''
```

Comment: Другими словами для каждого экземпляра переменную __log вы делаете независомой от переменной __log класса, как в случае с some_a.variable. Надеюсь так понятнее зачем я привел в примере эту ситуацию.

Comment: `Если задать ее значение через экземпляр, то __log этого экземпляра более не будет возвращать значение __log класса.` - если перезаписывать значение через экзепляр (или если изначально в поле лежит значение неизменяемого типа - как строка в вашем случае), то запишется в поле экзмпляра. Если же добавлять в список (без разницы - через экзепляр или через класс), то значение будет добавляться в список в поле класса: https://ideone.com/futX0f